# What exactly does invalid literal for int() with base 10 mean?

Tags: python

I am writing a movie sentiment analysis and in the code I am getting one error and that is: invalid literal for int() with base 10. The code reads a separate text file containg movie reviews with its score. ex) 4 This movie was great. Thanks for the help! Edit: the error appears here: line 38 score = int(lineSplits[0].strip())

```
import re
class WordStatistic:
    def __init__(self, keyword, averageScore = 0, occurences = 0):
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.averageScore = averageScore
        self.occurences = occurences

    def getWord(self) :
        return self.keyword

    def getAverageScore(self) :
        return self.averageScore

    def getOccurences(self) :
        return self.occurences

    def addNewScore(self, newScore) :
        oldScoreSum = self.averageScore * self.occurences
        self.occurences = self.occurences + 1
        self.averageScore = (oldScoreSum + newScore) / (self.occurences)

    def printWordStatistic(self) :
           print ("Word          : ", self.keyword)
           print ("Occurences    : ", self.occurences)
           print ("Average Score : ", self.occurences, "\n\n")
# "teaching" the code
wordDictionary = {}
fileInstance = open("movieReviews.txt",'r')
fileText = fileInstance.read()

# formatting and splitting 
reviewSplits = fileText.split("movieReviews")
for review in reviewSplits :
        review = review.strip()
        if review == "" :
            continue
        lineSplits = review.split("\n")
        score = int(lineSplits[0].strip())
        for i in range(1, len(lineSplits)) :
            wordSplits = re.split("\t| ", lineSplits[i])
            for word in wordSplits :
                if word == "" :
                    continue
                # If it is already present, then update the score and count
                # Otherwise just add the new entry to the dictionary
                if wordDictionary in(word) :
                    wordStatistic = wordDictionary.get(word)
                    wordStatistic.addNewScore(score)
                else :
                    wordStatistic = WordStatistic(word, score, 1)
                    wordDictionary[word] = wordStatistic
# print the stats of the words
def printAllWordStatistic(wordDictionary) :
    for wordStatistic in wordDictionary.values() :
        wordStatistic.printWordStatistic()
# rating the actual review
def calculateAverageOfReview(review) :
    review.replace("\t", " ")
    review.replace("\n", " ")
    wordSplits = review.split(" ")
    averageScore = 0.0
    totalCount = 0;
    for word in wordSplits :
        if wordDictionary in (word) :
            averageScore += wordDictionary.get(word).getAverageScore()
            totalCount = totalCount + 1
    if totalCount != 0 :
        return averageScore / totalCount
    return -1
# getting user input and append multi lines of case of multi line review
while (True) :
    print ("\nEnter a review : ");
    multiLines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            multiLines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    inputReview = '\n'.join(multiLines)
    averageScore = calculateAverageOfReview(inputReview)
    if averageScore != -1 :
        if averageScore >= 2.50 :
            print ("Positive Review");
        else :
            print ("Negative Review");
    else :
        print ("Unable to rate the review");
    if input("\nDo you want to continue ? (Y/N) : ") != "Y" :
        print ("Quitting the session.");
        exit()
```

Comment: It means one of the characters in the string is not in `1234567890.+-`. i.e. a character appears in the string that doesn't appear in base 10 arithmetic.

Comment: That's a whole lot of code for a single-sentence question.

Comment: You can probably narrow the problem down to one or two lines. Do that now, then present your [MCVE].

Comment: No it doesn't.  `int` will quite happily chew up whitespace and `-`, for example.  And it will *not* accept `.` character in strings.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `int` doesn't know what to do with characters that aren't `0-9`. If you have some arbitrary string that you want to pull a number out of, you could use regex, so instead of:

```
score = int(lineSplits[0].strip())
```

Something like

```
score = int(re.search('[0-9]+', lineSplits[0]).group()))
```

that will grab the first group of digits.